# FORCE_SSL_ADMIN: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': / Nginx Revserse Proxy

Tags: nginx, wordpress

Running Nginx as reverse proxy in SSL mode, backend is just Apache on port 8080. I am trying to figure out why I cant use define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);  without getting a redirect loop. To me there seems to be an issue with URLs in Wordpress

In my browser I see this:

```
 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL
```

Part of my wp-config.php

```
 if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
     proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
```

Part of my nginx.conf for the server bracket:

```
              proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header  X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
              proxy_redirect    off;
              proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

         proxy_pass http://IP:8080;
```

I also tried without the default, makes no difference

```
listen 443 default ssl http2; 
index index.php index.phtml index.html;
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to debug this since everything else seems in order?

Comment: What are you proxying to?!

Comment: Proxy to Apache

Comment: Better look at your Apache config, then. And, why even bother with Apache at all? You have nginx, you don't need Apache anymore.

Comment: CodeSpaces are using Nginx as a reverse proxy, and most of the docker containers are using apache to serve WordPress.  You don't have access to Nginx.